# What is sigma here?

Tags: vectors

[In this indentity](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GJO_4tCxDJtgzXIuxp2cmHjlvCoI5FLb/view?usp=drivesdk), what is sigma? I just started studying vector identities and this notation is used a lot in proving vector Identities

Comment: $\Sigma$ denotes a summation, here over a cyclic permutation.

Comment: $\Sigma$ is here the summation symbol.

Comment: @JeanMarie But summation wrt what?

Comment: The expression given is very ill-written : in order to understand it, you should  replace $I,J,K$ by $I_1,I_2,I_3$ and variables $x,y,z$ by $x_1,x_2,x_3$ ; in this way, the summation is with respect to indices ranging from $1$ to $3$.